# XNA very large images blurred

Tags: c#, xna

Not a problem as such - just want to learn. For some 30-frame high resolution 2D animations I was drawing I originally tried to tile them all into the world's largest sprite sheet - like a 30,000x1000 png. When I loaded this into XNA and tried to draw a portion of it, the image was very blurred and clearly at a much lower resolution. 
I'm not doing it this way now, I just wanted to learn a bit more about XNA and why it is doing this?

Comment: In order for anyone to answer this question, you would need to provide more details.  How did you draw the sprite sheet?  What is your code?  XNA doesn't draw blurry sprites unless you tell it to.

Comment: Thanks for your question! However, this is not really the kind of question that Stack Overflow is here to answer. [Read this for more information](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) Once you have a specific question about a specific problem you are having with code you are writing, feel free to return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum texture size in XNA using the HiDef profile is 4,096. I'm surprised it compiled & ran. Here's a list of limits: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff604995.aspx

I bet it's scaling your image down from 30,000 to 4,096 which is why it looks blurry.

Comment: Sounds like an answer - good to know!